# Does Python have standard fluent iterator operators like Java 8 Stream/Kotlin Sequence?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am a Java/Kotlin developer crash-coursing in Python to teach a class next year. I am a bit shocked that I am not finding any functional constructs to handle iteration with chain-like operators. This can be found in Java with Streams like so:

```
Stream<MyItem> filtered = myItems.stream().filter(item -> item.isSelected());
```

Or Kotlin with Sequences:

```
val filtered = myItems.asSequence().filter { it.isSelected }
```

I think Scala has something similar as well. I know it's possible to [implement fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Python) in Python, and [RxPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597358/rxpy-scheduling-understanding) brings these iteration operators via reactive programming. But is there no inherent language feature, standard utility, or common library that accomplishes these operators like `map()`, `filter()`, `flatMap()`, etc in a pull-based fashion?

Comment: Do you mean that you'd rather chain methods than wrap functions (`obj.func1().func2()` rather than `func2(func1(obj))`)?

Comment: I was noticing functions being nested, and I get they are objects. But yes, I would strongly prefer `obj.func1().func2()` syntax as its more functional. Do I have to implement these myself? If so, that's fine. But I hoped hundreds of iterative operators (`map()`, `flatMap()`, `groupBy()`, `filter()`, etc) would be available out-of-the-box.

Comment: Do you plan on teaching your students to write Java in Python, or is this only for your own use?

Comment: [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) are built in though? And map and filter are less idiomatic than list/generator comprehensions; `[item.isSelected() for item in myItems]`, `[item for item in myItems if item.isSelected]`, and so on.

Comment: @TigerHawkT3 I was asked to teach Spark via PySpark. I originally was going to teach Spark in a JVM language, so I plan on living and breathing Python at home so I can relate to participants as much as possible. Plus I'd like to know Python so using this as an opportunity.

Comment: But you're not living and breathing Python. You've got a full environmental suit that allows you to live and breathe Java while exploring Python's surface. The air is breathable here, I promise. You can take off your helmet. :)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Okay I see those now... still feels weird that I can't chain them.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 but... but... there's no types! And with no types, there is only room for anarchy and chaos! Haha I keed, I keed. I appreciate that :) I guess I'll have to settle for `map(lambda x: x * 100, filter(lambda x: x < 4, items))` rather than `items.filter(lambda x: x < 4).map(lambda x: x  * 100)`

Comment: You mean `x * 100 for x in items if x < 4`, right?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler that looks a bit better conciseness-wise. If that's as good as it gets without niche libraries then I'll accept as answer. Can you show full context too? But man, what happened to reading left-to-right? Then again I'm comparing to modern Kotlin/C#/Java 8 patterns, not traditional Java which is far less intuitive.

Comment: @ThomasN. comprehensions do read left to right: WHAT you want - LIST you want it from - WHERE predicate is satisfied. Its like map and filter in a little one-liner (FWIW, I still prefer method chaining).

Answer (score 1):

In Python we prefer for these patterns to use a syntax feature called
"comprehensions" - for example for this:

```
 val filtered = myItems.asSequence().filter { it.isSelected }
```

if we want an eager expression (i.e.: all items will be processed when the instruction is found):

```
 filtered = [item for item in my_items if item.is_selected]
```

(I did not call an equivalent to `asSequence`  method because in Python that usually is not needed: classes meant to be iterable just have to implement a method called `__iter__` and they can be plugged in a `for` loop just like above. Otherwise, an `as_sequence` method can work just the same, and be added to a class by using multi-inheritance mixins)

So, comprehensions allow for an "in expression" loop which iterates all items in an iterable, allow for a filter predicate after the `for ... in ...` pattern,  and execute the expression before the `for` for each item that pass the filter - that expression can be any Python expression.

That usually makes it shorter and more expressive than using the `filter` and `map` callables (which are also available if one is more confortable with then).

The alternate form:

```
  filtered = (item for item in my_items if item.is_selected)
```

is called a "generator expression" and can be further plugged in a `for` loop or passed along to a callable expecting an iterable to produce items lazily.

There are also syntaxes for creating dictionaries and sets just like the one for lists.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library that implements exactly what you are looking for:

[pyxtension](https://github.com/asuiu/pyxtension) on https://github.com/asuiu/pyxtension and it's also production ready and maintained on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pyxtension/).
This usual functional Py code like this:

```
lst = xrange(1,6)
reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, map(lambda _: _ * _, filter(lambda _: _ % 2 == 0, lst)))
```

can be rewritten into this:

```py
the_stream = stream( xrange(1,6) )
the_stream.\
    filter(lambda _: _ % 2 == 0).\
    map(lambda _: _ * _).\
    reduce(lambda x, y: x * y)
```

It supports multithreaded map, called [`fastmap`](https://github.com/asuiu/pyxtension#fastmapself-f-callable_k-_v-poolsize-int--cpu_count-buffersize-optionalint--none), and multiprocessed map called [`mpmap`](https://github.com/asuiu/pyxtension#mpmapself-f-callable_k-_v-poolsize-int--cpu_count-buffersize-optionalint--none).
It's prod ready and works out of the box, heavy using lazy evaluation with Python Iterators, so you won't load everything in memory like Pandas DataFrame does for processing. This pyxtension.streams is much more convenient for processing streams of data like CSV, Lined Json, MessagePack, DataBase cursors, etc...

With it you'll easily use all your CPU cores for parallel processing as workaround to GIL limitation.
Just run `pip install pyxtension` and it will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention the [`streamable`](https://github.com/ebonnal/streamable) module I wrote (would love to get feedback!):

Your example would look like:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Iterable
from streamable import Stream

@dataclass
class MyItem:
    name: str
    is_selected: bool

my_items: Iterable[MyItem] = [
    MyItem(name="foo", is_selected=True),
    MyItem(name="foo", is_selected=False),
    MyItem(name="foobar", is_selected=True),
]

my_items_stream: Stream[MyItem] = (
    Stream(lambda: my_items)
    .filter(lambda item: item.is_selected)
)

print(list(my_items_stream))
```

```
[MyItem(name='foo', is_selected=True), MyItem(name='foobar', is_selected=True)]
```

- this is a typed module with 100% code coverage and no dependency
- the `Stream[T]` class extends `Iterable[T]`
- a stream is ***immutable***
- operations are ***lazily evaluated*** and cover concurrency, grouping/flattening, exceptions catching, rate limiting, iteration progress logging, ...